# Como colocar um "mostrar mais" no gridview

Tags: c#, asp, gridview

Como fazer isso:

[image: GridView Simples]

Virar isso:

[image: Com os mesmos itens juntos em uma linha só, sendo que o principal tem a opção de mostrar os outros]

A única coisa que consigo imaginar é colocar uma treeview dentro da gridview, mesmo assim, nem sei se isso é possível.

A dúvida é só sobre a parte funcional mesmo, a parte estética eu vou fazer depois que resolver isso.

Comment: Com o gridview do webforms vai ser punk, já fiz uma vez com ele formatado usando o DataTables.net mas não é mamão com açúcar..RS ou usa o gridview do devexpress apesar de ser pago é bem fácil usar

Comment: Caso alguém precise, fiz do jeito que esse site mostra e deu certo: http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/expand-collapse-nested-gridview-asp-net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o gridview do webforms vai ser punk, já fiz uma vez com ele formatado usando o DataTables.net mas não é tão fácil se tiver q mostrar muitos dados na linha child
 ou usa o gridview do devexpress apesar de ser pago é bem fácil usar.

URL do Datatable.net plugin jquery gratuito que pode ser sua solução.
http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html